# Textfield - Label - Button Answers according to inputs

Tags: swift, xcode, button, label, textfield

I am very new to programming. But i am trying to improve myself and trying to what i am thinking. Here's my question.

I have 1 textfield 1 label and 1 button.

I want that when i write into the textfield for example "aaa" and press button i should see "bbb" in the label. This is first step. Actually i want to do this with some combinations. If i write "aaa bbb" and press button label must give me "ccc" as an answer. I know this is easy for you but stuck on it. I want all codes because as i said i am very new and try to myself by trying the codes for now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reform your question. Provide your current code and things you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

you add this code in your project.
step one:create textfield/label/button
step two:add button action
Code:

```
let textField = UITextField()
let label = UILabel()
let button = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
}

func setupUI() -> Void {
    //1.textField
    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
    textField.placeholder = "enter.."
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    view.addSubview(textField)
    //2.label
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 50)
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(label)
    //3.button
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 100, height: 50)
    button.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonDidTouch), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonDidTouch() -> Void {
    label.text = "ccc"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried but i got some errors :

Comment: Value of type "(Unbutton has no member of frame,background,add target)

Comment: This time i got only 1 error and that is "Argument of selector can not refer to local function buttondidtouch.

Comment: it can't be,this code is worked on my computer.are you sure your code as same as this code ?

Comment: @godisacoder You code is right it's running in my pc also.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You may see the screenshot. I know I expect all the codes from you but i need to get the logic in this way. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know you use the storyboard.you should delete my code,and just add `label.text = "ccc"`in your action.